# Libgdx/GooglePlayServices: How do I call to MainActivity(that extends BaseGameActivity, located in the Android Project) from the core project?

Tags: android, libgdx, google-play-services

I've read so many tutorials and Google documentation on how to implement Google Play Services into my Game, all in how are implemented solely in the Android project. However, LIBGDX has several other packages, namely the core project, where the core Game engine goes.
What I would I like to ask help for is:
For example, if in my core project, the player finishes the "match" and gets a score, and I would like to relay that score to Google Play Services, how do I call to the MainActivity to handle the "score"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say you have a "desktop" and "android" version of your game. Create an interface in your "core" project that handles all these Google Play Services events. For instance:

```
public interface GameEventListener {
    // Called when a score is to be submitted
    pubic void submitScore(int score);
}
```

Your game instantiation should now receive an implementation of this interface:

```
public class MyGame extends Game {

    public MyGame(GameEventListener listener) {
        // Keep the reference to this listener, you'll be calling it from your game
    }
}
```

Then, you have to make your DesktopLauncher and your AndroidLauncher implement this interface and pass themselves as an argument when you create your game:

DesktopLauncher:

```
public class DesktopLauncher implements GameEventListener {

    public static void main (String[] arg) {
        LwjglApplicationConfiguration config = new LwjglApplicationConfiguration();
        config.width = Constants.APP_WIDTH;
        config.height = Constants.APP_HEIGHT;
        new LwjglApplication(new MyGame(new GameEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void submitScore(int score) {
                // Handle the event as you wish for your desktop version
                Gdx.app.log("DesktopLauncher", "submitScore");
            }
        }), config);
    }        
}
```

AndroidLauncher (MainActivity):

```
public class AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication implements GameEventListener {

    // ... 

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // ... example code not intended to work, take only what you need

        // Create the layout
        RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        getWindow().clearFlags(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
        AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();

        // Game view. Pass the activity as the argument to your game class
        View gameView = initializeForView(new MyGame(this), config);
        layout.addView(gameView);

        setContentView(layout);
    }


    @Override
    public void submitScore(int score) {
        // Submit your score to Google Play Services
        gameServicesClient.submitScore(score);
    }

}
```

Now, whenever your "match" is over, send the message to your listener and it will call your MainActivity's implementation of "submitScore" if you are running the Android version of the game:

```
private void onMatchOver() {
    listener.submitScore(match.getFinalScore());
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you VERY much for that detailed explanation!!! I will try it out when I get back home, and let you know how it goes! : D

Comment: I'm now implementing your structure into my code, but found several issues. 1- It couldn't be done on the Desktop version, cannot pass a non-static value on the "new LwjglApplication(new MyGame(this), config);" part. 2- All the tutorials and documents are stating I should extend BaseGameActivity, and now I'm kinda wondering, relating to your structure, which class should extend BaseGameActivity? Thank you again : D

Comment: @coffeenet I wrote the code on the fly, sorry! I fixed the desktop version so it passes an anonymous implementation of GameEventListener, it should work now. Regarding the second question, if you want to extend from BaseGameActivity then your AndroidLauncher should be the one that does it. I personally didn't extend from it and instead used the GameHelper client from the same examples.

Comment: I see. Regarding the second question, do you mean you leave the AndroidLauncher extending AndroidApplication, and call to functions from the Gamehelper api instead of extending AndroidLauncher from BaseGameActivity?

Comment: something like this? https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/init#using_gamehelper_without_basegameactivity

Comment: @coffeenet correct, that's exactly what I use. Let me know if you need anything else!